# Use creeper spawner in structure (Minecaft forge mod 1.7.10)

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I tried to make a structure with a creeper spawner inside but I haven't found anything telling how to do.
I tried to see if I can make spawn the block with the metadata (52:50 for creeper spawner) but I haven't found anything using block metadata
And I also tried with a converter schematic to java but it don't exist for the 1.7.10 version

So could someone help me and tell me how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

For minecraft forge it's like that :

```java
// firstly we set the block as mob spawner
world.setBlock(xCoord, yCoord, zCoord, Blocks.mob_spawner);

// creating new mob spawner tile
TileEntityMobSpawner tileMobSpawner = new TileEntityMobSpawner();
world.setTileEntity(xCoord, yCoord, zCoord, tileMobSpawner); // using new object
// not define this tile with the required object type
tileMobSpawner.func_145881_a().setEntityName(EntityList.classToStringMapping.get(EntityCreeper.class));
```

For spigot, it's like that :

```java
Block block = world.getBlockAt(xCoord, yCoord, zCoord); // get block
block.setType(Material.MOB_SPAWNER); // set as spawner
CreatureSpawner spawner = (CreatureSpawner) block.getState(); // get block state to edit config
spawner.setSpawnedType(EntityType.CREEPER); // set required type
```